# ParseException mismatched input

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE PART(
p_partkey          decimal(5),
p_name             string,
p_mfgr             string,
p_brand            string,
p_type             string,
p_size             decimal(2),
p_container        string,
p_retailprice      decimal(5,3)
p_comment          string )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hive/part';
```

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 10:0 mismatched input 'p_comment' expecting ) near ')' in create table statement (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I tried add a bracket but it still isn't working. I'm unsure what does the error mean.

Comment: YOu are missing a comma before p_comment.

Comment: Commas don't have to be at the end of lines. It's easier to see the issue if you put it at the beginning of the next line

Answer (score 0):

use a comma to separate all columns. You have syntax error. Use belwo SQL pls.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE PART( p_partkey decimal(5), p_name string, p_mfgr string, p_brand string, p_type string, p_size decimal(2), p_container string, p_retailprice decimal(5,3), p_comment string )
```

Comment: Oh I just noticed it too, thank you.